# How to expose a tornado server serving websockets on dotcloud to the www?

Tags: websocket, tornado, dotcloud

I am trying to install the  [IPython html notebook server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/install/install.html#installnotebook)
on dotCloud. The IPython server uses tornado with websockets (and other internal communications using zeromq on tcp sockets).

Hhere's my **dotcloud.yml**:

```
www:          
    type: custom
    buildscript: builder
    ports:
       nbserver: tcp
```

I am following the custom port recipes given [here](http://answers.dotcloud.com/question/337/configure-ports-for-python-worker-web-server-eg) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065217/dotcloud-www-and-tcp-in-single-app/12066359#12066359). As the logs show, I run the tornado server on `127.0.0.1:$DOTCLOUD_WWW_NBSERVER_PORT`:

**/var/log/supervisor/www.log**:

> [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: 'http://127.0.0.1:35928/'
>   [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels.

But when I push, the dotCloud CLI tells me:

> WARNING: The service crashed at startup or is listening to the wrong port. It failed to    >respond on port "nbserver" (42801) within 30 seconds. Please check the application logs.
>   ...
>   Deployment finished. Your application is available at the following URLs
>   No URL found. That's ok, it means that your application does not include a webservice."

There's nothing on `my-app.dotcloud.com` or `my-app.dotcloud.com:DOTCLOUD_WWW_NBSERVER_PORT`

What am I missing here? Thanks for your help.

### UPDATE

Issue solved. The usual HTTP port works fine with websockets so the custom port recipes are not required. This is my new **dotcloud.yml**:

```
www:
 type: custom
 buildscript: builder
 ports:
   web: http
```

works with the following in `ipython_notebook_config.py`:

```
 c.NotebookApp.ip = '*'
```

This makes it so that the tornado webserver listens to all ip addresses.

**WARNING: setup security and authentication first!**

See [Running a Public Notebook Server](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#running-a-public-notebook-server) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Glad you got it working!

In the future, and for other readers, you actually want your app to listen on `$PORT_NBSERVER` and then connect to it on `DOTCLOUD_WWW_NBSERVER_PORT`. `$PORT_NBSERVER` is the local port while the latter is the port that's exposed to the outside world through our routing/NAT layer.

If you have any other issue, don't hesitate to reach out to us at http://support.dotcloud.com

*Source: I'm a dotCloud employee.*

Comment: Ok, but if the ws is being served via standard http port the DOTCLOUD_WWW_NBSERVER_PORT part shouldn't be necessary right? We should use http ports or tcp ones for websockets?